# Error trying to access the error property of AVPlaybackStatus

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, union-types, expo-av

I'm new to TypeScript and am trying to work with [expo-av](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/av/) for audio playback.

The following code gives me an error: `TS2339: Property 'error' does not exist on type 'AVPlaybackStatus'.`

```
const { sound, status } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(track.mp3);
if (status.isLoaded) {
  console.info(status.durationMillis);
}
else {
  console.error("track not loaded", status.error);
}
```

I looked at the definition of `status` and found:

```
export type AVPlaybackStatus =
  | {
      isLoaded: false;
      androidImplementation?: string;
      error?: string; // populated exactly once when an error forces the object to unload
    }
  | {
      isLoaded: true;
      androidImplementation?: string;

      uri: string;

      progressUpdateIntervalMillis: number;
      durationMillis?: number;
      positionMillis: number;
      playableDurationMillis?: number;
      seekMillisToleranceBefore?: number;
      seekMillisToleranceAfter?: number;

      shouldPlay: boolean;
      isPlaying: boolean;
      isBuffering: boolean;

      rate: number;
      shouldCorrectPitch: boolean;
      volume: number;
      isMuted: boolean;
      isLooping: boolean;

      didJustFinish: boolean; // true exactly once when the track plays to finish
    };
```

I have never seen this construct before but am guessing this is a [union or intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) (?).

How do I access `status.error`? And what is the typical idiom / construct to work with such types?

Comment: Make sure you have `strictNullChecks` enabled in your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Hm ok, I just disabled that yesterday because of other problems.

Comment: But you are correct, please convert to an answer.

Comment: @Oblosys, can you provide more info on why this is supposed to work? I'm trying to access `positionMillis`, but even when I turn on `strictNullChecks`, it doesn't seem to work. It keeps trying to tell me that that's not a property of the first type.

Comment: @JasonMasters There's more information in the answer below, including a link to the  documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pattern is the discriminating union ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions)), where TypeScript can exactly determine the type based on one field which is distinct for each of the alternatives. In this case it's the `isLoaded` boolean field, but for that to work, you do need to have `strictNullChecks` enabled. Other than that the way you're handling it is completely fine.

Comment: Thank you for the background!

Comment: I was a little confused. To make it more explicit: adding a `if(isLoaded) { ...} else {...}` allows TS to determine which type the object is.

Answer (score 0):

One tricky solution would be this:

```js
sound.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(status => {
  if ("didJustFinish" in status && status.didJustFinish) {
    console.log("Finished playing");
  }
});
```